# Moving from subdirectory to root

Tags: configuration, wsod

When I installed Drupal, I put it in a subfolder **/drupal**. Got everything set up and then moved everything into my root folder. When I went to the site I got this error:

```
Failed opening required '/home3/XXXX/public_html/drupal/modules/field/field.crud.inc'
(include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in 
/home3/XXXX/public_html/drupal/modules/modules/field/field.module on line 20
```

Then I moved everything back to **/drupal** and still get the same error.

Can anyone tell me where I should be looking for the issue?

I looked in my `settings.php` file and didn't see anything about a directory listing. I looked in `/sites/default/settings.php` and couldn't find anything to do with directories.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure you disabled APC and purged all cache* tables?

Comment: I got it fixed, I must have mistakenly moved a folder before hand. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for show the subdirectory site in the root I followed [this guide](https://drupal.org/node/144643).
I hope it could be usefull for you too ^^

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.